# How to filter data from SQL Server on datagridview using combobox in c#?

Tags: c#, filter, datagridview, combobox

My datagridview contains students information including their class (1A, 1B, 1C, 2A, 2B, 2C). Now I want to add combobox above the datagridview in order to filter which class will be shown on datagridview based on the combobox selection. 
Here is the code on my form:

```
private void frmdbStudent_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db = new StudentSMSEntities();
        studenttableBindingSource.DataSource = db.studenttable.ToList();
        classBindingSource.DataSource = db.class.ToList();
        GenderBindingSource.DataSource = db.gender.ToList();
        religionBindingSource.DataSource = db.religion.ToList();
        dataGridViewstudent.DataSource = db.studenttable.ToList();      
        count();
        cboClassList.DataSource = db.Class.ToList();//combobox
```

and here is the code of combobox:

```
private void cboDaftarKelas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridViewStudent.DataSource = db.studenttable.Where(stdnt => stdnt.ClassId == cboClassList.SelectedIndex).ToList();
    }
```

The code works, but when class 1A selected, the datagridview shows nothing, and when I select class 1B, datagridview shows students from class 1A, and so on.I wondering why this is happen and I've tried to solve this problem for many hours but still cannot find the solution.

Comment: Use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedIndex`

Comment: I've tried what you suggest, but I got this error "Severity Code Description "operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'object'".

Comment: Yeah you need to cast the `SelectedValue` to `int`

Comment: I don't have my lptp now, but I think you can do this `(int) SelectedValue` or `int.Parse(SelectedValue.toString())`

Comment: Thank you, I am still trying to do it @MohammadHamoud

Comment: @MohammadHamoud thankyou for your help, but its not working. I'll let you know if I can find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are binding the `Class` list to combobox `DataSource` set the `DisplayMember` and the `ValueMember` of the combo box as follows

```
cboClassList.DataSource = db.Class.ToList();

cboClassList.DisplayMember = "Name"; // value is an example
cboClassList.ValueMember = "Id"; // value is an example
```

Then when filtering the grid view data source do the following

```
dataGridViewStudent.DataSource = db.studenttable.Where(stdnt => stdnt.ClassId == (int) cboClassList.SelectedValue).ToList();
```

Or get the selected Item and cast it to the `Class` class and use its `Id` field

```
dataGridViewStudent.DataSource = db.studenttable.Where(stdnt => stdnt.ClassId == ((Class) cboClassList.SelectedItem).Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello @MohammadHamoud, I've try the code but it is not working. there is no error but it doesn't filter anything

Comment: can you put a breakpoint and check the values, also you can use immediate window to evaluate expressions to check the values of `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`

Comment: on the combobox property, on the the databinding, I set the selecteditem to classbindingsource - classname and Selectedvalue to studenttablebindingsource - classId

Comment: I didn't understand, can you elaborate what you meant in your question

Comment: you don't need to set the selected value and item, those should be set by the component when the user selects an item

Comment: I've set it to none. but still, It does not filter my datagridview.
It seems that your code is right and can solve this issue, but I don't know what I missed @mohammadHamoud

Comment: did you put break points, and check the values of the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` ?

Comment: Thankyou for your help @MohammadHamoud.
I'm going to learn about this breakpoint, how to put and set the value, because I am new to this.
for sure, I'll mark your answer later.